# forma de realizar um SELECT COUNT de forma mais rápida!

Tags: php, mysql

Preciso realizar uma consulta para saber um total de operadoras que possuo. Porem a tabela possui quase 18 milhões de registros, e esta demorando muito para retornar quase uns 3 minutos, e isso porque estou realizando teste direto no banco.

O problema sera maior quando esta tabela estiver completa, mais de 150 milhões, ai sim vai demorar uma eternidade, sera que tem alguma forma de realizar esta consulta de forma mais rápida?

```
SELECT *, COUNT(operadora) AS total_op
FROM telefones
GROUP BY operadora
```

Estrutura da Tabela

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `telefones` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `numero` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `ddd` int(3) NOT NULL,
  `operadora` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=19606524 ;

--
-- Extraindo dados da tabela `telefones`
--

INSERT INTO `telefones` (`id`, `numero`, `ddd`, `operadora`) VALUES
(31, '11920160030', 11, 'OI - Celular'),
(32, '11920160031', 11, 'TIM - Celular'),
(33, '11920160032', 11, 'Claro - Celular'),
(34, '11920160033', 11, 'VIVO - Celular'),
(35, '11920160034', 11, 'Claro - Celular'),
(36, '11920160035', 11, 'Claro - Celular'),
(37, '11920160036', 11, 'Claro - Celular'),
(38, '11920160037', 11, 'Claro - Celular'),
(39, '11920160038', 11, 'Claro - Celular'),
(40, '11920160039', 11, 'Claro - Celular'),
(41, '11920160040', 11, 'Claro - Celular'),
(42, '11920160041', 11, 'Claro - Celular'),
(43, '11920160042', 11, 'Claro - Celular'),
(44, '11920160043', 11, 'Claro - Celular'),
(45, '11920160044', 11, 'Claro - Celular'),
(46, '11920160045', 11, 'Claro - Celular'),
(47, '11920160046', 11, 'Claro - Celular'),
(48, '11920160047', 11, 'Claro - Celular'),
(49, '11920160048', 11, 'Claro - Celular'),
(50, '11920160049', 11, 'Claro - Celular'),
(51, '11920160050', 11, 'Claro - Celular'),
(52, '11920160051', 11, 'Claro - Celular'),
(53, '11920160052', 11, 'Claro - Celular'),
(54, '11920160053', 11, 'Claro - Celular'),
(55, '11920160054', 11, 'Claro - Celular'),
(56, '11920160055', 11, 'Claro - Celular'),
(57, '11920160056', 11, 'Claro - Celular'),
(58, '11920160057', 11, 'Claro - Celular'),
(59, '11920160058', 11, 'Claro - Celular'),
(60, '11920160059', 11, 'Claro - Celular'),
(61, '11920160060', 11, 'Claro - Celular'),
(62, '11920160061', 11, 'Claro - Celular'),
(63, '11920160062', 11, 'Claro - Celular'),
(64, '11920160063', 11, 'Claro - Celular'),
(65, '11920160064', 11, 'Claro - Celular'),
(66, '11920160065', 11, 'Claro - Celular'),
(67, '11920160066', 11, 'Claro - Celular'),
(68, '11920160067', 11, 'Claro - Celular'),
(69, '11920160068', 11, 'Claro - Celular'),
(70, '11920160069', 11, 'Claro - Celular'),
(71, '11920160070', 11, 'Claro - Celular'),
(72, '11920160071', 11, 'Claro - Celular'),
(73, '11920160072', 11, 'Claro - Celular'),
(74, '11920160073', 11, 'Claro - Celular'),
(75, '11920160074', 11, 'Claro - Celular'),
(76, '11920160075', 11, 'Claro - Celular'),
(77, '11920160076', 11, 'Claro - Celular'),
(78, '11920160077', 11, 'Claro - Celular'),
(79, '11920160078', 11, 'Claro - Celular'),
(80, '11920160079', 11, 'Claro - Celular'),
(81, '11920160080', 11, 'Claro - Celular'),
(82, '11920160081', 11, 'Claro - Celular'),
(83, '11920160082', 11, 'Claro - Celular'),
(84, '11920160083', 11, 'Claro - Celular'),
(85, '11920160084', 11, 'Claro - Celular'),
(86, '11920160085', 11, 'Claro - Celular'),
(87, '11920160086', 11, 'Claro - Celular'),
(88, '11920160087', 11, 'Claro - Celular'),
(89, '11920160088', 11, 'Claro - Celular'),
(90, '11920160089', 11, 'Claro - Celular');
```

Comment: Existe algum índice pela coluna `operadora`?

Comment: @ArturTrapp Não , esta direto com o nome

Comment: Porque você tá agrupando pela `operadora`? Além do mais, experimente criar um índice se não tiver, já tive ocasiões em que consegui fazer queries que demoravam três minutos passarem a levar menos de oito segundos

Comment: Por que `select *, count()`? Não bastava só o count?

Comment: @ArturTrapp - O Cliente importa tudo de um TXT, e joga no banco, e assim fica tudo agrupado!
Se eu alterar para incluir Indice, acho que na importação que demora um bom tempo, vai dobrar!

Comment: @ArturTrapp O Arquivo chega para ele desta forma  - 11999999999;Nextel - Celular

Comment: @jbueno Preciso listar o nome das operadoras e a quantidade de registros em cada uma.
Consigo realizar isso sem precisar de setar uma variável para isso?

Comment: @jbueno sem o `GROUP by` ele vai somar tudo, se fizer agrupada ele vai mostrar uma linha para cada operadora.

Comment: @MarcosPaulo acho que entendi o que precisa, realmente eu não tenho como testar 150 milhões, mas geralmente motores como innoDB tem um cache interno, também tem o myISAM que dizem ter melhor performance por ser mais simplório. Mas não posso afirmar muita coisa.

Comment: @MarcosPaulo, qual o impedimento para você colocar um indice na coluna da operadora? Note que os INSERTs vão sim perder um pouco de performance, mas isso vai depender muito do modo que você está fazendo. Se fizer dentro uma transação SQL a diferença vai ser bem menor.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento, o que me matou foi esta quantidade, vou ver o que consigo, o pior que ainda terei que contar por DDD também, ai pesa mais ainda!

Comment: @jlHertel vou tentar alterar aqui, o sistema de importação e de outro programador, ele criou um programinha para jogar direto no BD, acho que vou ter que criar uma aba no sistema onde sera importado o TXT, porem tem TXT de quase 500 megas

Comment: @MarcosPaulo, o tamanho do TXT não importa. O importante é garantir que os dados tenham o menor tipo possível e que estejam corretamente indexados. Uma solução alternativa que você pode tentar é criar mais uma coluna com a operadora usando um valor numérico, pois os números são muito menores e muito melhores no momento de indexar.

Answer (score 1):

Não há muito o que pode fazer, mas pode tentar descobrir o motivo do problema, com o `EXPLAIN`.

Primeiro, o MySQL tenta sempre utiliza *indexes*, sua tabela não possui nenhum indexação desta coluna, porque não cria?

O MySQL tem três escolhas:

- Utiliza o `index`.
- Se não conseguir utilizar o `index` <sub>(não existir é um dos motivos)</sub>:

  - Utilizará uma *"temporary table"*.
  - Utilizará um *"filesort"*.

---

Você pode forçar o *"temporary table"* usando o `SELECT SQL_SMALL_RESULT ...` ou forçar o *"filesort"* usando o `SELECT SQL_BIG_RESULT ...` como consta [no manual do `SELECT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html).

---

Você pode criar *index* utilizando o `CREATE INDEX ...`, [como consta no manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-index.html) ou utilizando o `ALTER TABLE`, exemplo:

```
CREATE INDEX nome_do_index on nome_da_tabela(nome_da_coluna) using HASH;
```

O motivo do uso do `HASH` ao invés do `BTree` é porque você não vai comparar "operadoraA > operadoraB", mas irá comparar "operadoraA != operadoraB" ou "operadoraA = operadoraA".

---

Uma das maneiras para contornar o problema é criar uma tabela "Contagem_Operadora" e atualiza-la frequentemente, ou seja um "CACHE". Dessa forma ao invés de sempre calcular basta fazer `SELECT contagem WHERE operadora = 'oi'`, como já está *pre-calculado* o retorno será muito mais rápido.

Comment: Verdade, bem pensado, como as operadoras serão sempre as mesmas, não ira aparecer uma com tanta frequencia, posso modificar, assim creio que resolve 95% do meu problema

Comment: Parece que mesmo colunas indexadas (fiz um teste com 9 milhões de registros) é um pouco demorado, talvez a melhor maneira realmente seja cache.

Comment: Haveria diferença no *count* se no lugar de `operadora varchar(15)`, fosse `operadora int(11)`? Sabe se influencia de alguma forma?

Comment: No count em especifico não sei, mas... Diferença haveria, o INT são sempre 4 bytes, assim como o TINYINT é 1 byte. O VARCHAR não tem tamanho fixo, porque existem caracteres que são multi-bytes, no caso do VARCHAR(15 CHAR), são 15 caracteres, considerando que no UTF-8usa de 1 até 4 bytes por letra nos temos até 60 bytes. Usando TINYINT pouparia no minimo 252 MB (18000000 * 14 / 1000000) e no máximo 1062MB (18000000 * 59 / 1000000). Obviamente isso deve acelerar, além dos indexes serem mais leves.

Comment: Valeu pelas informações